# How should I do integer division in Perl?

Tags: perl, integer-division

What is a good way to **always** do integer division in Perl?

For example, I want:

```
real / int = int

int / real = int

int / int = int
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can cast ints in Perl:

```
int(5/1.5) = 3;
```

Comment: Yes, but integer division would be int(5) / int(1.5).  Otherwise, you're just rounding the real division.

Comment: but int(5) / int(1.5) != int

Comment: Sorry, this is what I was really asking for.  I was wanting an int result after doing any sort of division.  So yes, I was looking for rounding.

Comment: Beware floating point rounding problems: `int(-6.725/0.025)` is -268 and `POSIX::floor(-6.725/0.025)` is -269 [see perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/int.html)

Comment: It is completly wrong, because with intiger division we completly drop all numbers after dot. then with int math  5/1.5 is 5/1 eq 5 not 3 as in this example. Also it is wrong when we round up/down numbers, then 5/1.5 is 5/2 eq 2.5=>3, but it equals witn int(5/1.5) by accident. it is not rule.

Comment: The comments here are confusing and quite wrong in some cases. If you're looking for integer division the way it works in C (where all values after the decimal are _truncated_, not _rounded_) this answer will work. Note though that as @maxpolk points out, the perl docs recommend `POSIX::floor`.

Comment: @ShaneHughes I agree with Shane. "Integer division" is truncation (not rounding) after dividing -- it doesn't mean that the inputs are truncated first, so Rog and Znik are quite wrong. I don't know of any language so broken that dividing 5 by 1.5 yields 5 ... not `int(5/1.5)` in C++ or `(int)(5/1.5)` in C or `5//1.5` in Python. P.S. Hah! The exception! `use integer;` in perl ... but that's brain damaged.

Answer (score 93):

There are at least 2 reasonable answers to this question. (I originally gave only answer 2.)

1. Use the `int()` function to truncate the floating-point calculation result to an integer (throwing away the decimal part),  as Bryan suggested in his self-answer: [#539805](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539797/how-should-i-do-integer-division-in-perl#539805)
2. Use the [`use integer` pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/integer.html) to make Perl truncate *both* the inputs and results of calculations to integers. It's scoped to within `{ }` blocks.

Examples:

```perl
print 3.0/2.1 . "\n";      # => 1.42857142857143
print 5.0/1.5 . "\n";      # => 3.33333333333333

print int(3.0/2.1) . "\n"; # => 1
print int(5.0/1.5) . "\n"; # => 3

{
  use integer;
  print 3.0/2.1 . "\n";    # => 1
  print 5.0/1.5 . "\n";    # => 5 (because 1.5 was truncated to 1)
}
print 3.0/2.1 . "\n";      # => 1.42857142857143 again
```

Comment: Additional info, parentheses separate 'use integer' inside block, then outside the block, will be used standard real calculation both before and after block.

Comment: Without using 'use integer' you can always write -1 & $x which returns the integer value of $x ...

Comment: @johannesvalks That will turn negative integers into positive twos-complement numbers, which is probably not what you wanted.  'use integer' is also problematic, as it is *signed* integers, so will completely screw up large unsigned numbers.  use integer also has implementation defined behavior with negative inputs on C89 compilers.  Casting via int(a/b) is going to be wrong for most large inputs.  Getting consistent results for all inputs is *really* hard.

Comment: You are changing the definition of "integer division" in the entire history of modern computing and perhaps mathematics! See the link for what integer division actually is. Your method yields 5 for 5/1.5, while integer division yields 3.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zvse/6.2?topic=SSB27H_6.2.0/fg1rr_integer_division.html

Comment: Fair point @FNia, although that meaning was Perl's choice, not mine. I revised my answer.

Comment: @MichaelRatanapintha Thanks for the revision. I'm not sure if Perl officially refers to that method a "integer division", but if I've missed it in the docs please point to it.

Answer (score 8):

`int(x+.5)` will round *positive* values toward the nearest integer. Rounding up is harder.

To round toward zero:

`int($x)`

For the solutions below, include the following statement:

`use POSIX;`

To round down: `POSIX::floor($x)`

To round up: `POSIX::ceil($x)`

To round away from zero: `POSIX::floor($x) - int($x) + POSIX::ceil($x)`

To round off to the nearest integer: `POSIX::floor($x+.5)`

Note that `int($x+.5)` fails badly for negative values. `int(-2.1+.5)` is `int(-1.6)`, which is -1.

Comment: No, `int` rounds toward zero, while normal rounding it toward even. Run `perl -le 'printf "int(%s) is %d, round(%s) is %.0f;\n", ($_+0.5)x4 for -10..10'` and you will see things like int(-3.5) is -3, round(-3.5) is -4; int(-2.5) is -2, round(-2.5) is -2; int(-1.5) is -1, round(-1.5) is -2; int(-0.5) is 0, round(-0.5) is -0; int(0.5) is 0, round(0.5) is 0; int(1.5) is 1, round(1.5) is 2; int(2.5) is 2, round(2.5) is 2; int(3.5) is 3, round(3.5) is 4; int(4.5) is 4, round(4.5) is 4;

Comment: @tchrist Actually, normal rounding is towards nearest; only the border case .5 rounds towards even.

Answer (score 4):

you can:

```
use integer;
```

it is explained by Michael Ratanapintha or else use manually:

```
$a=3.7;
$b=2.1;

$c=int(int($a)/int($b));
```

notice, 'int' is not casting. this is function for converting number to integer form.
this is because Perl 5 does not have separate integer division. exception is when you 'use integer'. Then you will lose real division.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works

int(9/4) = 2.

Thanks
Manojkumar

Answer (score 0):

Integer division $x divided by $y ...

`$z = -1 & $x / $y`

How does it work?

`$x / $y`

return the floating point division

`&`

perform a bit-wise AND

`-1`

stands for

`&HFFFFFFFF`

for the largest integer ... whence

`$z = -1 & $x / $y`

gives the integer division ...

Comment: `perl -E 'my($x,$y)=(-12,4); my $z = -1 & $x/$y; say int($x/$y); say $x/$y; say $z;'` will give: -3, -3, 18446744073709551613.

Answer (score -2):

Eg
9 / 4 = 2.25

int(9) / int(4) = 2

9 / 4 - remainder / deniminator = 2

9 /4 - 9 % 4 / 4 = 2

Comment: This answer is completely wrong.

"int(9)/ int(4) == 2.25", so I think Paul meant int(9/4)

Comment: I think he didn't test his examples